# Nested grid with extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I can put grid in the plugins of another grid.

this is my grid and I want to put in the config 'plugins' ext grid.

```
 var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: store,
                    columns: [
        { header: 'Customer Name', dataIndex: 'CustomerName', width: 212 },
        { header: 'Charge Date', dataIndex: 'ChargeDate', width: 212 },
        { header: 'Package Plan', dataIndex: 'PackagePlan', width: 212 },
        { header: 'Current Invoice Sum', dataIndex: 'CurrentInvoiceSum', width: 212 }
     ],
                    plugins: [{
                        ptype: 'rowexpander',
                        rowBodyTpl: ['<div style="background-color:#CBDDF3; width:643px;margin-left:147px;margin-bottom: 20px;border: 1px solid;">',
            '<p><b>Customer Details:</b><br/>{CustomerName}<br/> {CustomerAddress}, {CustomerPhone}, {CustomerEmail} </p>',
                                '<p><b>Package Type:</b> {PackagePlan}<br/>',
                                '<b>Invoice Details:</b></p>',
                   '<div class="nestedO" id="{InvoiceId}"></div> </div>',
        ]
                    }],
                    width: 900,
                    height: 450,
                    renderTo: Ext.get('Ongoing')
                });
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Nested grids are possible. Here is a solution from Sencha forums:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151442-Nested-EXTJS-4-Grids&p=668193&viewfull=1#post668193

You almost got it. In the plugin part, we will create a empty div to which we will render our nested grid:

```
plugins: [{
        ptype: "rowexpander",
        rowBodyTpl: ['<div id="SessionInstructionGridRow-{ClientSessionId}" ></div>']    
}],
```

And when user expands the grid row, we will render the nested grid into it.

```
expandbody : function(rowNode,record, expandbody) {
    var targetId = 'SessionInstructionGridRow-' + record.get('ClientSessionId');
    if (Ext.getCmp(targetId + "_grid") == null) {
        var sessionInstructionGrid = Ext.create('TS.view.client.SessionInstruction', {
            renderTo: targetId,
            id: targetId + "_grid"
        });
        rowNode.grid = sessionInstructionGrid;
        sessionInstructionGrid.getEl().swallowEvent(['mouseover', 'mousedown', 'click', 'dblclick', 'onRowFocus']);
        sessionInstructionGrid.fireEvent("bind", sessionInstructionGrid, { ClientSessionId: record.get('ClientSessionId') });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tell you my problem:
I want to create the nested grid when creating the parent grid and not when 'expandbody'.I want to load data one time and part of the data use in the parent and part of them in nested
Maybe you have any idea about it. Thanks

Comment: In the above code, there is no extra data load happening. I am binding the parent's record info to the nested grid. The only thing happening at expandbody is creating instance of the nested grid and rendering.

Comment: By the way, what does it mean "TS.view.client.SessionInstruction"?

Comment: Its just my view's name (Nested grid's name).. give your appropriate nested grid's name so that ExtJS can instantiate it.

Comment: I can put instead of this 'Ext.gridPanel' ?

Comment: maybe you can vote me so we can discuss in chat.
if I use  'Ext.gridPanel' it say that it is not constructore

Comment: I have used the above code successfuly but the problem I got is with the width of my innergrid.When I add single child grid to my parent grid,everything works fine but when I add two child grids,the child grids VIEWS take the width I specify in the DIV but the grid table gets the width of parent grid.