# Does ExtJS 4.1 supports nested grids?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Does ExtJS 4.1 supports nested grids?
If Yes, can I create a new grid in rowexpander?
I have tried creating new XTemplate but nothing seems to work in rowBodyTpl, apart from basic HTML.

Comment: This stack question looks similar to your issue using rowexpander.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254113/nested-grid-with-extjs-4

Comment: I have already tried it, but doesn't works.  Also, it is not properly explained that where we need to implement the changes & all.

Comment: have you tried this link: [Nested Grid](http://mikhailstadnik.com/ext/examples/nested-grid.htm) Actually, developer made for ExtJS 3.0 but you can refactor the code.